# How to find the Host IP of my multiplayer game

Tags: c#, xna

I am writing a simple multiplayer 2d game, 4 player Pong to be exact.

When the game starts There is a start Menu where you can choose to host or join a game.
one of the 4 players has to host, the other 3 will join.  I can yell across the room to my other 3 buddies and tell them my ip and port number, but I am wondering if there is a way to search for the host instead.  To me it sounds impossible, there are millions of computers on the internet, how can I possibly find the one computer who is waiting for my call.  I know StarCraft Used to do it in the mid 90's.

I have one theory on how I can achieve this.  That is using a database like sql to keep track of who is currently Hosting.  This would be the only use of the database since I am not keeping user stats or anything.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes I believe so, it is a huge work network, 1000's of computers, we are on the same domain if that is the same thing

Comment: But I want to move beyond the local network, or at least be able to if I wanted to

Comment: Not that this helps what you need right now, But if you wanted a nice platform beyond local, I found playerIO.com to be a great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on a LAN, you can use UDP to discover clients.

If a client is acting as a host, it listens for UDP datagrams. If it receives one containing a discovery request, it responds with its IP, port and any other information that the client needs. (You can include number of connected players, etc.)

If a client is acting as, well, a client, it sends discovery datagrams while on the "join a game" screen. As hosts respond, they are added to the selection list.

When the user selects a server, connect over IP as you're already doing using the IP and port that you received in the discovery response.

The [Lidgren network library](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) provides some nice Discovery functionality that may be of use.

If you're not on a LAN, you'll need some sort of central directory that's globally accessible- probably on a website. When someone starts a new game, their client would register their IP, etc. with the directory. Clients would then poll that site to get a list of servers, which would then be used to populate the "Join a game" screen.

It's worth noting that the server/directory approach works just as well in a LAN environment as it does over the Internet. UDP is more flexible in that it doesn't require that a client have any knowledge of a directory provider, since it basically "yells across the room" for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need a central broker to identify those that are hosting and those that are participating.

You'll also probably want to pass the game traffic through that selfsame host too, because there are a lot of issues with opening ports and passing direct traffic between remote computers behind other firewalls, etc. Also if you keep the traffic centralized you can put in some checks and balances against cheating.

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of server (web/ftp) on the internet that you can write a file to. When you're hosting a game write the IP and port in the file. When a client wants to join a game a function can check for the file and read it. This is just the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Yes. The only (practical) *general* solution is to have a central authority to manage bookkeeping. At least, as far as I know :-)

Comment: This sounds the same as a database.

Comment: actually I don't think it's a very good idea. consider two cases first both players are going to play over the lan connection, consider how many people share same IP addresses over local address (for example almost all routers have "192.168.1.1"). and even if they want to play over the internet, usually routers will block any connection, simply because they don't know how to handle a TCP request from unknown place over the internet.

Comment: @Gajet: Think outside the box a little. First, if you're on a LAN, you would write the internal ip address of the client, not the public wan side address of the router. Second, routers don't "usually block any connection." Where did you get that from? If I'm running a server on my machine and it's listening on a port that I defined, then obviously I'll make sure that my router is forwarding the necessary ports.

Comment: while you computer doesn't have a valid IP. you either have to send you iternal address to the server or your external address. as I said sending internal address won't produce any benefits caused by two simple facts, first there are many computer all over the world with similar internal addresses. When someone is trying to play over the LAN there is a noticable chance he is not connected to internet. And if you want to send your external address, I agree you can forward the necessary ports, but still you ***need*** to forward them. only listening specified ports won't solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for LAN use only, it would be possible for each client to send a UDP broadcast to the network subnet's broadcast address.

The hosts (or other clients) listens on the same UDP port.